# Getting the value of a nested map in erlang

Tags: erlang

I have a nested map in erlang and I can't figure of how to get the value of a key from it properly.

```
A = #{"key1" => "val1", "key2" => #{"key3"=>"val3", "key4" => #{"key5" => "val5"}}},
```

I want to extract the value of `key5` and so far I've tried this.

```
    A = #{"key1" => "val1", "key2" => #{"key3"=>"val3", "key4" => #{"key5" => "val5"}}},
    S = maps:get("key2", A),
    SS = maps:get("key4", S),
    Val = maps:get("key5", SS),
    Val.
```

I know it's working but I'm pretty sure there is a better way to do it!

Answer (score 3):

You can use pattern matching to extract the value of `key5`:

```
A = #{"key1" => "val1", "key2" => #{"key3" => "val3", "key4" => #{"key5" => "val5"}}},
#{"key2" := #{"key4" := #{"key5" := Value}}} = A,
Value.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try create recursive function, eg:

```erlang
-module(nm).

-export([nested_map/0]).

-define(KEY, "key5").

nested_map() ->
  Map =   #{"key1" => "val1", "key2" => #{"key3"=>"val3", "key4" => #{"key5" => "val5"}}},
  get_val(maps:keys(Map), Map, ?KEY).

get_val([], _, _) ->
  undefined;
get_val(_, #{?KEY := Val}, ?KEY) ->
  Val;
get_val([H|T], Map, Key) ->
  case is_map(maps:get(H, Map)) of
    true -> 
      NewMap = maps:get(H, Map),
      get_val(maps:keys(NewMap), NewMap, Key);
    false ->
      get_val(T, Map, Key)
  end.
```

In shell:

```erlang
1> c(nm).
{ok,nm}
2> nm:nested_map().
"val5"
3>
```

Comment: thats clearly the better solution, as pattern matching relies on the correct sorting of the keys you are trying to match...so if your map contains some more complicated object and you (as in most cases) cannot guarantee how the keys are sorted (because the parser which build it actually doesn't care, then you have very hard times to pattern match this correclty. A recursive getter is better here and actually nested data is still a mess in erlang unfortunately. So I have to upvote this.

Comment: Pattern matching in maps doesn't care about "key sorting" and works reliably regardless of the order in which the keys are defined or displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Probably special library can be concerned as solution for the task:

https://github.com/Shaienn/nested_maps

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33199458)